# How to get the unicode from a emoji in c++ or cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

If I have a emoji like "",In the code, is:

```
std::string emojiStr = "";
```

On the webSite,the table shows this emoji's unicode like :"U+1F31E"

And please teach me how can I get this unicode from the string "" in c++/cocos2dx?

Comment: To understand this fully, you should learn about encodings: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/). If `std::string` (which stores `char`s) can present your emoji with code point U+1F31E then it might store the UTF-8 sequence and your text editor might resolve this correctly. (These are two "might"s.)

Comment: Assuming that I was right with UTF-8, you could provide the bytes for UTF-8 encoded code point U+1F31E () with the resp. sequence of [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for the bytes: `"\xf0\x9f\x8c\x9e"` (according to [UTF8 Encoder](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode)).

Comment: `std::string emojiStr = u8""` should properly store UTF8 string with any modern C++ compiler. Maybe you have trouble printing Unicode on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks for your answer, Scheff!

I find the example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt and write a foolish method as I see. But it can work after all.

Here is the code:

```
std::string EWUtils::emojiToStr(std::string str)
{
    std::ofstream(FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename("text.txt")) << str;
    std::wifstream fin(FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename("text.txt"));
    fin.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

    std::string name;
    for (wchar_t c; fin >> c; )
    {
        __String* item = __String::createWithFormat("%x",c);
        name = name + item->_string + "-";
    }
    if (name.length() > 1) {
        name.pop_back();
    }
    return name;
}
```

I know it is really not necessary to write the string into a txt file. But if the example write so, I just follow it.

I'm really a beginner. If somebody have the better way, welcome to show.